# How to create an entity based on an existing table

Tags: symfony

I create manually through `make:entity` and I get an error - `An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT d0_.id AS id_0 FROM document d0_':

SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "document" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT d0_.id AS id_0 FROM document d0_^`

Tell me how to create an entity based on an existing table?

I tried using `doctrine:mapping:import`, but it doesn't work, I read that the method is deprecated